# "das geht prima" verstehen

Tags: meaning

> Ben sagt: „In Berlin mit dem Fahrrad unterwegs sein, das geht prima“
>
> Frage: Ben findet, dass ein Fahrrad in der Stadt sehr nützlich ist (Richtig oder falsch?)

Ich habe *richtig* gewählt, aber leider ist es nicht die richtige Lösung. Warum? Ist es vielleicht falsch, weil Berlin keine einfache Stadt ist, sondern eine Hauptstadt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ben sagt *nichts* darüber, ob ein Fahrrad in Berlin *nützlich* ist oder nicht.

Er sagt (ähnlich, aber nicht dasselbe): "Es geht" - Hier in einer Bedeutung wie "es funktioniert/ist möglich", "lässt sich machen", "ist akzeptabel".

Deine Vermutung über die Hauptstadt kann ich nicht bestätigen - Obwohl Berlin die Hauptstadt ist, sagen wir immer noch (auch) "Stadt" dazu.

Comment: Vielen danke . Ich habe eine andere Vermutung . In dieser Teil war Ben mit dem Fahrrad entlang an der Spree. Und morgen wird er mit dem Fahrrad auf der Straße fahren "unter den Linden" vielleicht In der Stadt hier unterscheidet sich von entlang an der Spree ??

Comment: Ich bin völlig tofro's Meinung, und kann deiner Vermutung nicht zustimmen. Ben hat schlicht und ergreifend nichts über die _Nützlichkeit_ gesagt, nur über die gute _Möglichkeit_. Natürlich ist es richtig, dass das Fahren auf einem Radweg entlang der Spree einfacher ist, als quer durch die Innenstadt, aber Ben hat klar von _Berlin_ (im Sinne von _ganz Berlin_) gesprochen, und keine solche Unterscheidung erwähnt. Insofern ist deine Vermutung zwar technisch korrekt, ergibt sich aber nicht aus der Aufgabenstellung - und ist daher irrelevant.

Comment: @AhmedRamadan Morgen wird er vielleicht sagen "Man muss sich zwar zwischen den Autos durchquetschen, aber es geht" - Damit meint er aber immer noch nicht, dass Fahrradfahren in Berlin *nützlich* ist - Sondern "nur" akzeptabel.

Comment: Danke , ich habe gedacht, dass "es geht prima" Toll bedeutet.

Comment: @AhmedRamadan Das war auch richtig gedacht. Allerdings ändert das nichts daran, dass er nicht sagt "Es ist toll nützlich", sondern "Es funktioniert gut"

Comment: Es wäre auch möglich, dass Radfahren in Berlin eine Zumutung ist, aber dennoch nützlich, weil es keine bessere Alternative gibt. Zum zu Fußgehen ist aber vieles in Berlin zu weit, BVG zu teuer, Autos auch teuer und Parkplätze zu suchen zeitraubend und nervenaufreibend. Je nach sportlichkeit ist man bis 5 oder 10 km mit dem Rad oft schneller, und in diesem Umkreis lässt sich schon viel erledigen. "Geht prima" ist aber eine bessere Bewertung als "ist akzeptabel". "Funktioniert gut" trifft es m.E. besser.

Comment: OK, ich bin hier dann in der Minderheit, weil ich glaube dass Nutzen vs Vergnuegen (bloede Tastatur) hier nicht den Kern trifft: Die Aussage war, dass **in Berlin** ein Fahrrad super/prima/toll ist. Ich sage mal, dass das auch was positives ueber den Nutzen aussagt. **Aber**, die Frage ist dann, ob ein Fahrrad _in der Stadt_ nuetzlich ist. In _welcher_ Stadt? Keine Aussage, ob es sich hier um Berlin speziell handelt, sondern nur generell in einer beliebigen Stadt. Damit wird es zu einem non-sequitur - nur weil Berlin fahrrad-freundlich ist, trifft das ja wirklich nicht auf alle Staedte zu.

Comment: Kurz gesagt: der Lehrer/Fragesteller sollte keine solchen spitzfindigen Fragen stellen! :-P

Comment: "mit dem Fahrrad auf der Autobahn auf der linken Spur unterwegs sein? Das geht nicht prima" - Ist das besser? Hier ist weder nach Nutzen noch nach Vergnügen gefragt, sondern nach "funktioniert das?" (akzeptabel ist es auch nicht)

Comment: @tofro Gibs zu, du warst der Lehrer, der die Frage gestellt hat! ;)

Comment: @Marakai Ehm, nein. Aber ich kann nachvollziehen, dass der Lehrer versucht, Fragen zu finden, die die im Deutschen manchmal ein wenig umfangreiche Bedeutungsvielfalt von "gehen" abprüfen.

Comment: @tofro *grummel, grummel, grummel* ist immer noch eine gemeine Trickfrage *grummel, grummel, grummel*

Comment: Wenn ich nicht wüsste, dass es sich um eine Fangfrage handelt, würde ich auch *richtig* wählen. Nimmt man es genau, ist es das natürlich nicht. _(Welch ein Wunder, dass es vielen schwer fällt, Deutsch zu lernen...)_

Comment: Ich *gehe* davon aus, das es in den vorher*gegangenen* Lektionen um das verb "gehen" *gegangen* ist. Dann sehe ich, ehrlich gesagt, keine "Fangfrage".

Answer (score 2):

I guess the answer is wrong for the following reasons:

1. Ben talks **specifically** about Berlin, not any given city
2. Ben doesn't say anything about using a bike is **useful**. He just says that it is easy to get around in Berlin using a bike, but not whether he sees any advantage in doing so.

Comment: See, that's my problem: in all earnestness, when would you not see it as **also** being **useful** when something is **easy** and **fun**? Unless you are talking about pure entertainment value. Just think about our gadget driven world: unless it's easy and fun, you don't care how useful it is. Games exempted, naturally.

Comment: The fact that something works well (like going by bike in Berlin) doesn't necessarily mean it has advantages over other methods of transportation. So going by bike in Berlin may work well, but it may not be more or less useful than for example going by car. That means that Ben doesn't make **any** representation about whether he thinks going by bike is useful. He just says it works.

Comment: The problem is that this then becomes an exercise in semantics, not language! While my comments may have seemed flippant, I actually have a serious problem: are we really talking about a language teacher who was putting "traps" like this into a questionnaire or test or exam? Just look at us - German speakers, most, if not all, native, and we are discussing minutiae of meaning. "could mean"; "doesn't necessarily mean". It's ridiculous! I feel for Ahmed, because his teacher is a mongrel!

Comment: There's no language without semantics. These tests are about understanding the meaning of sentences and no matter what language: you can not "read more from a sentence" than there is. That doesn't make the test bad or the teacher a bad person. It just shows that you need to practice your reading competence :-)

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree. Maybe it's because I deal with documents, technical and contractual, where such "deeper semantics" are anathema. I expect things to be spelled out clearly, lest they lead to issues, both expensive and legal (which is **also** expensive).

Comment: Esp. if you deal with documents that require a certain degree of precision you should agree to what I'm saying :-) if Ben talks about Berlin you can not generalize his statement to be true for any city and just because he says something works well doesn't imply it is useful in general.

Comment: Wait! But that's what I said in a comment on one of the other answers!

Comment: Well then read my answer and the other comments again. That's all I've been saying all the time and also the reason why the answer in the original question is wrong. And that's why this is not a trick question by the teacher but a question about text competence. 

Comment: I think the whole discussion would have been resolved quite quickly if we'd gotten any idea at what level of language competence this test was taking place. I still maintain that it was a "mean" question, but that said, I would agree with you that at a fairly advanced level of language studies, such as vocational or professional, this sort of insight and reflection would be necessary. But would such a person have needed to ask?

Comment: This kind of question is asked in your native language classes, too (in Germany in fifth grade latest). You don't need a university degree to answer them.

Comment: I don't think we will see eye to eye on this. It's becoming a bit pointless. Maybe I've been gone from Germany too long and no longer appreciate sophistry like I used to. <shrug> Edit: whoops! No, I'm not accusing **you** of sophistry! Sorry if that nearly came across wong!

Answer (score 2):

In Bens Aussage wird die gestellte Frage nicht beantwortet. Deshalb ist "falsch" die richtige Antwort auf die Frage.

"Das geht prima" bedeutet hier, dass es keine Probleme gibt, wenn man in Berlin mit dem Fahrrad unterwegs ist.

Comment: `[...] bedeutet` **`hier[...]`** Würde ich eine solche Aussage treffen - egal ob in Berlin oder einem eher hochdeutsch geprägten Raum - wäre es _dort_ wohl nicht so präzise gemeint... Aber ja, das ist wohl die richtige Antwort auf diese Frage.

Comment: "falsch" ist ebenso falsch. Die korrekte Antwort wäre "wir wissen es nicht", weil wir nicht in Bens Kopf gucken können.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is wrong, because a bicycle is a very handy means of transport in a city as flat as Berlin, but in a more hilly city, like for example in Stuttgart or Zürich, to name only two, Ben would say something different altogether.

So the part "in der Stadt", which means "in a city-esque environment", as opposed to "in the city of Berlin" in this context, makes the answer wrong: Ben refers to a specific city, not any city in general.

The part "das geht prima" is not the problem: You were right there. This is a colloquial expression and could be translated as "works like a charm".